# How to avoid using styles of a specific css file for a specific div?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a webpage which has 2 css files called style1.css and style2.css . 
In the webpage there is a div that should not use styles which are in style2.css.
How can i do this?

Comment: Usually by adjusting the style rules in style2.css and make sure that no selector matches that specific diff. Otherwise by adding new rules with more specific selectors which define the style you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] *there is a div **that should not use styles** which are in* [...]

This is the art of CSS architecture.

You need to give some thought to:

- the **order** in which you write rules; and
- **how** you write the selectors for those rules

A good approach is to write your rules, in order from:

### the most general => ... to ... => the most specific

That is, you will *start* with the most general, most widely-applied rules at the top of the cascade and *then*, as you proceed down the cascade, gradually zero-in on exceptions on a more and more granular basis.

**e.g.**

```
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 + p {
  font-weight: 700;
}

footer h2 + p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

The example above declares three style rules:

- Unless otherwise stated, `<p>` elements should have a `font-size` of `16px` and a normal `font-weight`
- the ***exception*** to the first rule above is when a `<p>` element immediately follows an `<h2>` element, in which case it should have a **bold** `font-weight`
- the ***exception***, in turn, to the second rule above is when the `<h2>` element followed by the `<p>` element is, itself, contained in a `<footer>` sectioning element, in which case it should have a normal `font-weight` after all, but also have a smaller `font-size` of `12px`

Using this approach you will find that, most of the time, you won't need to **undo** styles you have already applied because you will never apply the styles until you need them.

Answer (score 1):

don't call the second css file on that page. Or give the div a unique id and only write styles for it in style1.css